# DataSet OR DataReader for this case

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, dataset, sqldatareader

I have a need to iterating through 2 tables, first iterate 1 tables and based on its value fetch and iterate the other table. It likes

```
GetAllEmployeeName
```

For each employee get and iterate **All Sub Employees** and do some **OPERATION**.

Now I am using **ADO.NET** for this *fetching* and *keeping data*.

Since my data are huge i.e the sub-employee are many(around 10,000) to one employee.

And the operation I am doing is quite time taking i.e it also make a web service call for each sub employee.

Should I keep them in a `DataSet` or `SqlDataReader` for my case, considering **performance** and **no database locking**..

Comment: There will **always** be database locking - you cannot totally avoid that.

Comment: USing DataSet...I dont think we are locking..it will be a one time lookup only..

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to load data, use SqlDataReader. 
SqlDataAdapter/DataSet allows you to iterate both forward and backward the result, as well modify it.  Also, see this: [SqlDataAdapter vs SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676753/sqldataadapter-vs-sqldatareader/1676797)