# Return SqlDataReader with closed connection

Tags: c#, ienumerable, sqldatareader

I have created a Sql helper class which handles most of my needs.

Amongst those, I have a function which executes a SQL statement and returns a SqlDataReader as follows:

```
public static SqlDataReader ExecuteCommand(string cmdText, bool useParameters)
{
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString.ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
        {
            if (useParameters && SqlParameterCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(SqlParameterCollection.ToArray());
            }

            using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                return sqlDataReader;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is, obviously, the fact that it returns a sqlDataReader which requires an open connection and the fact that the connection is closed.

I have looked at returning a SqlDataAdapter instead, but after reading the following thread [SqlDataAdapter vs SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676753/sqldataadapter-vs-sqldatareader) it doesn't sound like such a good idea as a general function to be used in every single scenario when you have absolutely no idea of the amount of data it is supposed to load.

So... What's a good alternative?

The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is to cycle through the rows in the SqlDataReader and do a `yield return IEnumerable<IDataRecord>`.

Is there any better way of achieving this or is this pretty much it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`, which offloads closure to the caller - *but* this then makes your code dependent on the caller `using` the reader correctly.

Personally, I would try to minimize this type of dependency - and move the materialization code as close to the DB code as possible. In reality, there aren't that many cases when the caller needs a raw reader - or at least, there shouldn't be. I would strongly advise using tools like "dapper" or ORMs, so that you can just do something like:

```
return connection.Query<T>(cmdText, args).ToList();
```

which then doesn't leave many places for the caller to make a mess of things.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was after.

Comment: How about this use case: I have a class that handles Transformation jobs on a data warehouse (DWH). The query of each job needs to be executed on the DWH (an SQL Server), and the results need to be copied to one or more different databases. These could be SQL Servers as well, but might be different database servers as well. I want to get a reader from my Sql server layer, but might need to use it in a Postgress or MariaDB db layer. Looks like I need to break the decoupling somewhere, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper for your connection and reader, which implements `System.IDisposable`. The wrapper becomes responsible for closing the connection:

```
public class DbReaderWrapper : IDbReaderWrapper
    {
        public DbDataReader Reader { get; private set; }
        private readonly DbConnection _connection;
        private bool _disposed = false;

        public DbReaderWrapper(DbConnection connection, DbDataReader reader)
        {
            Reader = reader;
            _connection = connection;
        }

        ~DbReaderWrapper()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if(_disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if(disposing)
            {
                _connection.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

Your `ExecuteCommand()` function would look something like this:

```
public static SqlDataReader ExecuteCommand(string cmdText, bool useParameters)
{
    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString.ConnectionString)
    sqlConnection.Open();
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection)

    if (useParameters && SqlParameterCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(SqlParameterCollection.ToArray());
    }

    var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    return new DbReaderWrapper(sqlConnection, sqlDataReader);
}
```

And you can call this method with the `using` statement:

```
using var readerWrapper = sqlHelper.ExecuteCommand(query, true) {
    // Do something with the reader
}
```