# C# best way to populate List with SQLite DB

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

What is the best way to populate a List using a SQLite DB. 
I had been using SQLiteDataAdapter and one of a colleague of mine told me that it is not a great choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `SqliteDataReader`.

```
 using(SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();

            string stm = "SELECT ListItem FROM Table";

            using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(stm, con))
            {
                using (SqliteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read()) 
                    {
                        //add items to your list
                    }         
                }
            }

            con.Close();   
         }
```

From [this article](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitecsharp/read/).

> The SqliteDataReader is a class used to retrieve data from the
>   database. It is used with the SqliteCommand class to execute an SQL
>   SELECT statement and then access the returned rows. It provides fast,
>   forward-only, read-only access to query results. It is the most
>   efficient way to retrieve data from tables.

This comparison is for SQL Server, but the result is the same: [SqlDataAdapter vs SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676753/sqldataadapter-vs-sqldatareader)

Another comparison chart here from [this article](http://onlydifferencefaqs.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/difference-between-datareaderdataset.html).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Do you know why it is not that great?

Comment: @doro, I just added a comparison to the answer.