# Why I can't display data from database in HTML table in ASPNet.aspx

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to display some data from an SQLserver to an HTML table in ASPNet, this is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;


namespace WebApplication17
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Populating a DataTable from database.
            DataTable dt = this.GetData();

            //Building an HTML string.
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            //Table start.
            html.Append("<table border = '1'>");

            //Building the Header row.
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<th>");
                html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                html.Append("</th>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");

            //Building the Data rows.
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                html.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }

            //Table end.
            html.Append("</table>");

            //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
        }
    }


    private DataTable GetData()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, Nome, Cognome FROM Anagrafica"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
               }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

and this is my HTML markup so far:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication17.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
     <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID = "PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

The proble is: I keep on getting an NullReferenceException error on constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

I can't fix it...any ideas please? Thanks in advice.

Comment: Make sure you have defined `constr` in Web.Config file. Also, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it to know about the error.

Comment: @RahulSingh can you please provide me a sort of code for declaring it? I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Connection String in your Web.Config file something like this in the `configuration` node:-

[Working with Configuration file & Connection Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="constr" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
       connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=
             |DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" />
    </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
```

These are basics, you should refer to some tutorails from MSDN.

Comment: thanks! It worked! but now for some other reasons I got this error: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code on                             sda.Fill(dt);

Comment: @FabioEnne - Don't create DataTable using `using` like this - `using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())`, create it as a normal instance like this: - `DataTable dt = new DataTable(); sda.Fill(dt);`

Comment: @ RahulSingh Done it, but keep on getting the same error on sda.Fill(dt);

Comment: @FabioEnne - I am not sure whats going wrong. Please search for this error, it happens when connection is not open or when a connection is already open.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution that works:

```
private DataTable GetData()
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NB465\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Movie;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, Nome, Cognome FROM Anagrafica");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Some quick advice, maybe use SqlDataReader instead of Adapter. (Data Adapter is usually used for manipulating data, Reader will be quicker)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676753/sqldataadapter-vs-sqldatareader