# Data from the Database doesn't load on the datagrid view

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I was currently working on a project and wants to load the called data on the datagridview upon form_load, But I wasn't sure why the supposed data wasn't loading. Attached are my codes, could you help me pinpoint whats wrong with this? Needed it badlly.

Code:

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = GetV9_data();

        }

        private DataTable GetV9_data()
        {
            DataTable V9db = new DataTable();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = 10.47.48.80; Initial Catalog = V9_Hirata_L2; User ID = Guest; Password = ************;";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ID, MotorSN, StationNo, PT_NestNo, PT_TS_AW_Pin_1, PT_TimeIn FROM tbl_V9_Datalog", conn);

            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            V9db.Load(reader);

            return V9db;
        }
```

Comment: try using an SqlDataAdapter in stead of a SqlDataReader

Comment: What does the debugger say: Has the Table rows & data?

Comment: Debugger says nothing, as I am able to run the code. No red highlights nor error logs

Comment: @GuidoG whats the difference between the two?

Comment: you can read about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676753/sqldataadapter-vs-sqldatareader)

Comment: _Debugger says nothing, as I am able to run the code_ You need to __learn__ about using the debugger then! It will tell you all the more if the code __is__ running!! Set a __breakpoint__ after the load and look at the datatable!!